# find cumulative sum and then store in a vector

Tags: r, cumulative-sum

I have a vector `test = c(2,4,6,8)` and I need to find the cumulative sum in the loop for k in 1:4 and then find the upper and lower bound. The code is below:

```
for(k in 1:4){
  l[k] = (cumsum(test[1:k]) - 1.96)/k
  u[k] = (cumsum(test[1:k]) + 1.96)/k
}

max_l = max(l)
max_u = max(u)
```

I get a warning

> In l[k] <- cumsum(test[1:k]) :
> number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"

I need to find the cumulative sum from 1 to k and then use the formula in the code above to find lower and upper bound and then find the max among them.

Comment: `l[k]` is one single value - `test[1:k]` is `k` values (1, 2, 3 or 4 depending on which iteration the loop is up to). You can't store >1 values in one value, hence the warning.

Comment: How do I get one single value for l[k]?

Comment: I think you possibly just want `sum` instead of `cumsum` in your function.

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it only prints the last value when I tried doing 1000 simulations

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a loop. If I have understood you correctly you are trying to do :

```
test = c(2,4,6,8)
l <- (cumsum(test) - 1.96)/seq_along(test)
u <- (cumsum(test) + 1.96)/seq_along(test)

l
#[1] 0.04 2.02 3.35 4.51
u
#[1] 3.96 3.98 4.65 5.49

max_l = max(l)
max_u = max(u)

max_l
#[1] 4.51
max_u
#[1] 5.49
```